# Center Select drop down inside div

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm struggling to centre a select drop-down inside a div. I've tried both margin: auto; and text-align: centre; to no avail

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U8Kja/

Can anyone figure this out? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 26):

Add this to the bottom of your fiddle.

```
select {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The margin auto on right and left side will center a block element within the parent div.

Comment: Your answer should contains an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 6):

You had set `text-align:centre`

It should be `text-align:center`

[Check demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U8Kja/5/)

Comment: Ah yes, I am such an r-tard, can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @SparrwHawk Ya that was the only issue.

Comment: @SparrwHawk Accept this as the correct answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
text-align-last: center
```

Comment: When answering a seven year old question with four existing answers it is useful to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses, and to acknowledge if the passage of time has impacted the answer. You might consult https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-align-last to note when this became widely available in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
text-align: center
```

The error is in text-align: **centre**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
    /*These options are for the div to be visible in the example, the important is the first*/
    border:1px solid black;
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
}

.cmb {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <select class="cmb">
    <option value=1>Option 1</option>
    <option value=2>Option 2</option>
    <option value=3>Option 3</option>
  </select>
<div>
```